# Asp.net Core 6 Problem With Identity On IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I Have An Strange Problem With Asp.net Core 6 On IIS that Using Identity To Handle Authentication And Authorization .

The Problem Is When I Successfull Login To Application , Every MVC Controllers Are Available except Question Controller (One Of My Controller Name Is Question).

When I Try To Call "/Question/MyQuestions" Authorize Attribute Redirect Me To "/Account/Login"
Despite Of User Still Authenticated .

This Problem Is Only On IIS . Everthing Works Fine On LocalHost VisualStudio 2022

I Dont Know Where is My Problem

I Try To Remove Authorize Attribute And Test Another Controller With Authorize Attribute . But The Problem Is Still Exist

This Is My Custom ServiceCollection Extention

```
 public static void AddMVCPattern(this IServiceCollection service)
    {
        service.AddControllersWithViews();
        service.AddMvc()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix).AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
    }
    public static void AddRequierments(this IServiceCollection service, Dictionary<string, string>? razorPages, bool hasRazorPage = false)
    {
        service.AddSession((options) =>
        {
            options.IOTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        });

        if (hasRazorPage)
        {
            service.AddRazorPages((options) =>
            {
                foreach (string key in razorPages.Keys)
                {
                    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute(key, razorPages[key]);
                }
            });
        }

        service.AddLocalization(option => option.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        service.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>((options) =>
        {
            CultureInfo[] cultures = new CultureInfo[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("fa-IR"),
                new CultureInfo("en-US")
            };

            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "fa-IR", uiCulture: "fa-IR");
            options.SupportedCultures = cultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = cultures;

            options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>()
            {
                new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
            };
        });

        service.ConfigureApplicationCookie((cookie) =>
        {
            cookie.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            cookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            cookie.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
    }
```

This Is My Important Part Of My Program.cs

```
 var builder = ServiceHost.CreateHost(args);

        builder.Services.AddMVCPattern();
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<ForumContext>();
        builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, Role>((options) =>
        {
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 6;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = true;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ForumContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddErrorDescriber<CustomDescriber>();
        builder.Services.AddRequierments(new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"/Profile","/User-Profile"}
        }, true);
```

THis Is Program.cs Middlewares Area

```
   var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error"); //------Get Errors 500 Only
            app.UseErrors(); //-------Get Errors Except 500 
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        else
        {   
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseErrors(); //-------Get Errors Except 500 
        }

        app.UseSession();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseRequestLocalization(app.Services.CreateScope().ServiceProvider
            .GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);

        //--------Create Default Admin User
        app.Services.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetService<IAddUser>().AddAdminAsync().Wait();

        //--------Update Question ReviewCount Using Middleware
        app.UseUpdateQuestionReview();
        app.MapRazorPages();
        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Forum}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        app.Run();
```

This Is My Login Action Method

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Login")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromForm] LoginVM login)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(new
            { Message = MessageManager.GetMessage("error.badrequest", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name) });
        }

        User foundUser = await _general.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(login.Username);
        if (foundUser != null)
        {
            if (foundUser.isActive)
            {
                SignInResult result =
                    await _general.SignInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(foundUser, login.Password, true);
                if (result.IsNotAllowed)
                {
                    //---Send OTP TO Verify Mobile
                    ServiceResponse response = await SendSMS(foundUser);

                    if (response.StatusCode == 200)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Verify-Account");
                    }

                    TempData["Error"] = MessageManager.GetMessage("error.notallowed", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
                }

                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    //---Show Message To User
                    TempData["Error"] = MessageManager.GetMessage("error.lockout", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
                }

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    AuthenticationProperties props = new AuthenticationProperties()
                    {
                        AllowRefresh = true,
                        ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20),
                        IsPersistent = true
                    };
                    List<Claim> defaultClaims = new List<Claim>()
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, foundUser.UserName),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, foundUser.Email),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.MobilePhone, foundUser.PhoneNumber)
                    };
                    await _general.SignInManager.SignInWithClaimsAsync(foundUser, props, defaultClaims);

                    return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Forum"));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Error"] = MessageManager.GetMessage("error.user.deactive", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
            }
        }
        TempData["Error"] = MessageManager.GetMessage("error.credential", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
    }
```

This Is My Problem Area . MyQuestion Action Method Redirected To /Account/Login

```
    [Authorization(ClaimList.MyQuestions)]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/Questions/Asked/List")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MyQuestions()
    {
        ViewData["Title"] =
            MessageManager.GetMessage("my.question.view.page.title", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
        User loggedInUser = await _general.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(this.User.Identity.Name);
        QuestionListVM vm = new QuestionListVM()
        {
            MyQuestions = _general.MyQuestions.GetMyQuestions(loggedInUser.Id)
        };
        return View("MyQuestions", vm);

    }
```

At Least I Have A Custom Authorization Only For Check LoggedIn User Claims To Access Controllers And Action Methods

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class Authorization : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public Claim Claim { get; set; }

    public Authorization(string claimType)
    {
        this.Claim = new Claim(claimType, "true");
    }
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var userHasClaim =
                context.HttpContext.User.Claims.Any(x => x.Type.ToLower().Equals(this.Claim.Type.ToLower()) && x.Value.ToLower().Equals(this.Claim.Value.ToLower()));
            if (!userHasClaim)
            {
                context.Result = new RedirectResult("/Error/Access-Denied");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If application is working on IIS Express launched by Visual Studio and it behaves differently or real IIS then I would suggest checking `web.config` file

Comment: Please rewrite your question. In English, hardly any words are supposed to be capitalized, This Is Unreadable. But your appear to have invented your own authorization system, but you don't set the appropriate claim when the user logs in? Debug that.

Comment: What Should i Check in Web.Config File ?  jgasiorowski